# Cropping frustration in iPhoto 11 -> iMovie 11

Tags: ilife, slideshow

1. set up a slide show.
2. select 'sliding panel' theme. Set aspect ratio to 4:3
3. observe that, on the very first image, the program has chosen a bad crop. there's uninteresting stuff on the right (next to the text title) and not enough of the left side.
4. use the hand tool to move the image and fix the crop.
5. export to a quicktime movie using 'custom export'
6. play quicktime movie with quicktime player
7. observe that cropping is now *different* -- back more or less to the original.
8. import into iMovie
9. image is then recropped on the left, resulting in complete frustration.

Any way out of this? Is there something about aspect ratio that I don't understand, or is iLife 11 just buggier than a new york hotel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have it set to `Preserve Aspect Ratio: Letterbox.`

Photo [in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/least-annoying-export-format-for-iphoto-imovie).