# Least annoying slideshow export format for iPhoto to iMovie

Tags: ilife, slideshow

When percolating slide shows from iPhoto '11 to iMovie '11, what is best format to choose for export to minimize wasted disk space and time, given that I do not want to carry any audio? I've been using QuickTime, on the theory that Apple's programs would behave best with Apple's format, but I'm beginning to wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264) codec that the QuickTime format uses is a part of [MPEG-4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpeg4).
To get the best results, tweak the options for MPEG4.

Go File → Export → Slideshow → Custom Export → Movie to MPEG-4 → Options….
Below is a screen cap of the options I recommend for you. You can adjust the resolution and bitrate depending on the quality you want (higher numbers = higher quality).

[image]
[image]